# How to disable the xfce4-terminal's scrollbar with an option in the terminalrc file?

Tags: terminal, xfce, xubuntu, xfce4-terminal

I would like to configure xfce4-terminal (in Xubuntu 16.04) only by using the terminalrc file, not by using the GUI interface.

The terminalrc file is the file where I can configure different options according to [the xfce4-terminal's documentation](https://docs.xfce.org/apps/terminal/advanced).

- its location: $HOME/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc
- examples of option:

  - MiscMenubarDefault=FALSE
  - MiscToolbarDefault=FALSE

In the previous link, I cannot find any option to disable the scrollbar.

The question is, is there an option in the terminalrc file to disable the scrollbar? And, supposing the answer is yes, what is this option?

Comment: The option to disable the scrollbar is trivial to find in the graphical Preferences window. If you're curious how it's stored in the config file, you can easily answer it for yourself by comparing its contents before and after modifying this option on the GUI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [egmont](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/53656/egmont) suggested in a comment, the option to disable the scrollbar can be found by disabling it in the GUI and then, searching in the `terminalrc` file the added line.

Edit this file: `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc`

The option to add in the `terminalrc` file to disable the scrollbar is:

```
ScrollingBar=TERMINAL_SCROLLBAR_NONE
```